# I need something to look at the characters in a string and accept the string if it only has the certain characters in Java

Tags: java, string, character, contains

The statement will return true if the string has these characters in it. "-1234567890". If the string has anything else but these characters the statement will return false. The characters can be in any order and any amount, just as long as it contains those characters. So String a = "12-3"; would return true but String b = "1a3-"; would return false. ** Also it cannot go through a for loop.

Comment: Learn about regex, they will empower you more than you think.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is a string called `input` you can do this

```
input.matches("^[0-9\\-]*$")
```

This answers your exact question - but I second the comment stating to learn more about regex, you will find it useful more than you would think.

Comment: This didn't work, it says the \- is an illegal escape character.

Comment: You don't need the `^` and `$` anchors with `matches()`. Also, you don't need to escape `-` when it's at the end of a character class. So, `matches("[0-9-]*")` should work just as well. Or, if you want to use `\d`: `[\\d-]*`.

Comment: If you exclude the `^$`, would the expression not also match against a string that started with a letter, or ended with a letter? Isn't that the purpose of the `^$` to ensure the entire string matches the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
String str;

str.matches("^[0-9-]*$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ,matches already has ^ $ characters so you don't have to put this characters. `\\d` means `[0-9]` and `-` is not a special character so you don't have to put `\\` 
and you should + instead of * because I assume that you don't want to matched empty string to your regex.

So you should use :

```
s.matches("[\\d-]+");
```

code :

```
String arr[] = {"1-23a456-", "a123","123-","-","1","123123fwdf234","123-3453",""};
for (String string : arr) {
    System.out.println(string + "==>" + string.matches("[\\d-]+"));
}
```

output :

```
1-23a456-==>false
a123==>false
123-==>true
-==>true
1==>true
123123fwdf234==>false
123-3453==>true
==>false  \\ empty string
```